# knockout: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'newCommentText'

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have code like this in my view model:

```
function ChatListViewModel(chats) {
    var self = this;

    self.newCommentText = ko.observable();

    self.addComment = function(chat) {
      var newComment = { CourseItemDescription: this.newCommentText() };
      chat.CommentList.push(newComment);
      self.newCommentText("");       
    };

}

ko.applyBindings(new ChatListViewModel(initialData));
```

but I get this error when I try to add a new comment:

[image]

any Ideas what I'm doing wrong? I looked at some knockout samples on the knockoutjs.com webpage and this is how they were doing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this.

```
self.addComment = function(chat) {
   var newComment = { CourseItemDescription: self.newCommentText() };
   chat.CommentList.push(newComment);
   self.newCommentText("");       
};
```

Your this variable is not what you expect.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have the same problem, except I want `addComment` to be a function on the prototype, where `self` is not longer available.  Any ideas how to do this?