# Knockout 2.2.0 error with jQuery 1.9

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, jquery-1.9

I copied one of examples of knockoutjs:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>JS Bin</title>

    </head>
    <body>


    <h2>Participants</h2>
    Here are the participants:
    <div data-bind="template: { name: 'person-template', data: buyer }"></div>
    <div data-bind="template: { name: 'person-template', data: seller }"></div>





    <script id="person-template" type="text/html">
        <h3 data-bind="text: name"></h3>
        <p>Credits: <span data-bind="text: credits"></span></p>
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
         function MyViewModel() {
             this.buyer = { name: 'Franklin', credits: 250 };
             this.seller = { name: 'Mario', credits: 5800 };
         }
         ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());
    </script>
    </html>
```

When I updated jQuery to **Version 1.9**, I'm got following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (e,t){return new st.fn.init(e,t,X)} has no method 'clean'
```

I'd appreciate it if someone could explain if the bug is in jQuery or KO.

Comment: Try updating Knockout to `2.2.1`.

Comment: Did this previously work with an earlier version of jQuery?

Comment: It seems it works with KO 2.2.1 and jQuery 1.9.0 http://jsfiddle.net/MExgF/

Comment: Possible dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11022829/knockout-uncaught-typeerror-object-object-has-no-method-newcommenttext

Comment: right, now i see it is working with 2.2.1, anyway still where is the bug not clear

Comment: The error was caused by Knockout. See my updated answer below.

Comment: I had the same issue. Upgrading to Knockout 2.2.1 solved it.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**The Cause**

You are not using the most current version of Knockout. The previous version, 2.2.0, is incompatible with jQuery 1.9.x and on. See [this Knockout dev thread](https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/pull/796):

> Knockout 2.2.0 uses jQuery.clean() which is deprecated and does not exist in 1.9.

This means that Knockout 2.2.0 is calling an undefined jQuery method, thus triggering the JS error you specified.

**Solutions**

1. Consider updating to **[the latest version of Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/downloads/index.html)** which is compatible with jQuery 1.9
2. If you can't, use the **[jQuery Migrate
   plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/#readme)** which adds
   backward-compatibility to jQuery 1.9
3. If all else fails, you'll need to revert back to **[jQuery 1.8](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js)**

Comment: Confused... I thought Knockout had no dependencies and was pure JavaScript?

Comment: @FooBar Knockout is indeed not depended on jQuery. However, it does include jQuery-specific code, in order to make it easier to use the two libraries together. One such outdated code snippet was included in Knockout 2.2.0 and generated an error when Knockout was used with jQuery. See [the 2.2.0 source](https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/blob/gh-pages-2.2.0/js/knockout-2.2.0.debug.js) (line 706).

Comment: Updated link to the [2.2.0 source](http://cloud.github.com/downloads/knockout/knockout/knockout-2.2.0.debug.js).

Answer (score 8):

Updating Knockout to 2.2.1 solves the problem for me:

- **2.2.0**: http://jsfiddle.net/UDSBC/2/
- **2.2.1**: http://jsfiddle.net/UDSBC/1/

So just change:

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

To:

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.2.1/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

And it'll work.