# How to correctly include jQuery with knockout.js in ASP.NET MVC5

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, asp.net-mvc-5

I created an MVC project in VisualStudio 2017.

Edit:
I updated knockout aand jQuery to newest versions.

I have included my .js file at the bottom and it works fine until I try to use jQuery.

In my .js file:

```
function job(name) {
    return {
        name: ko.observable(name)
    };
}

var viewModel = {
    jobs: ko.observableArray([new job("johnny"), new job("anderson")]),

    addJob: function () {
        this.jobs.push(new job("Another job"));
    },
}
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

the markup:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/knockout-3.4.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<h3>Jobs:</h3>
<ul data-bind="template: {name:'jobsTemplate', foreach:jobs}"></ul>

<script id="jobsTemplate" type="text/html">
    <li>${ $data.name }</li>
</script>
```

and the page spits out 2 `<li>` with the text ${ $data.name } meaning to me that jQuery isn't included. I am able to use jQuery in the console.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What version of JQuery are you trying to load?

Comment: Also is there any particular reason you're using such an old version of knockout?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Knockout 2.2.0 error with jQuery 1.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14475781/knockout-2-2-0-error-with-jquery-1-9)

Comment: It's the version that loaded into the Scripts file via NuGet.. lemme look at that. Wow, jQuery was really old too.. Now I know to check updates via NuGet.

Comment: That syntax `<li>${ $data.name }</li>` isn't something that is natively supported by either knockout or jquery as far as I know. Are you using handlebars.js?

Comment: There's the problem, Jason! I didn't realize that syntax wasn't built into knockout. You have to add a template library, like handlebars, mustache or, in this case, jquery.tmpl Thanks so much!

Comment: you're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Knockout templating works through regular knockout data binding.

```html
<ul data-bind="template: {name:'jobsTemplate', foreach: jobs}"></ul>

<script id="jobsTemplate" type="text/html">
  <li data-bind="text: name"></li>
</script>
```